# Using Lists in webservice

Tags: c#, .net, list, exception, asmx

I am making a webservice (can't shift to wcf due to .net req). My WebServiceRequest Class has list of other classes in it. I get below error when I try to compile code:

```
request.List = list;
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'ServiceReference1.foo[]'

This error goes away when i do `request.List = list.ToArray();` 
but when i run the code i get this exception:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
>   http://localhost:60380/fooService/fooService.asmx. This could be due
>   to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This
>   could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the
>   server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs
>   for more details.

Inner Exception:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive.

Server stack trace:

> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException
>   webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   ServiceReference1.testpingtestSoap.Calculatetestping(CalculatetestpingRequest1
>   request)    at
>   ServiceReference1.testpingtestSoapClient.ServiceReference1.testpingtestSoap.Calculatetestping(CalculatetestpingRequest1
>   request) in c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\test\2e05987f\91110734\App_WebReferences.rwmro5zd.0.cs:line 855 
>   at
>   ServiceReference1.testpingtestSoapClient.Calculatetestping(CalculatetestpingRequest
>   _request) in c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\2e05987f\91110734\App_WebReferences.rwmro5zd.0.cs:line 862 
>   at testCost2.Calculatetestping() in
>   c:\Users\User\Desktop\test\InfoSystem\testping\testCost2.aspx.cs:line
>   203  at testCost2.Submit_Go(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\User\Desktop\test\InfoSystem\testping\testCost2.aspx.cs:line
>   148  at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Edit 1:
Request & Responce Classes of Web Service

```
 public class Item
    {

        public List<string> Composites { get; set; }
        public string Composites_List { get { return string.Join(", ", Composites.ToArray()); } }



        public List<px> pxes { get; set; }
        public List<ox> oxes { get; set; }

        public List<MethodCalculationType> MethodCalculationTypes { get; set; }
        public ShippingItem() { }
        public void ShippingItemFill(string sku, int quantity)
        {
            \\this method is just written to avoid parameterless constructor error
        }
        public static ItemComparison = delegateItem item1, Item item2) { return item1.Area.CompareTo(item2.Area); };
    }
   public class Request
    {
        public List<Item> ItemList;
        public bool showAllRatesField;
        public bool m_Ignore;
        public string pTextField;
        public decimal TotalField;

            }
    public class Responce
    {
        public od [] ods;

    }
```

Comment: @Tobias when i put a simple string in the request and no List<> it run perfectly, if you still think its a problem of configs any idea what would be misconfigured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, you can use as many `Lists<>` in your parameters to webservice as you want,  here's what i found; in case someone needs it:

`1.` Enabled dignostics on server by adding below to web.config on server side

> > `<system.diagnostics>
> >         <trace autoflush="true" />
> >         <sources>
> >           <source name="System.Web.Services.Asmx">
> >             <listeners>
> >               <add name="AsmxTraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
> >     initializeData="local.log" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack,
> >     DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId" />
> >             </listeners>
> >           </source>
> >         </sources>
> >         <switches>
> >           <add name="System.Web.Services.Asmx" value="Verbose"  />
> >         </switches>   </system.diagnostics>`

`2.` When Http Exception occured; in log file it wrote `error reading or writing a variable` i looked up that variable in webservice code and that variable was `internal`, removed internal keyword from that variable and the code started working.

Turns out `soap` needs paramerters to be serialized so any varaible in your custom parameter class should be public read/write. as mentioned by John Saunders [here](http://qa.social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/e24e2bf9-ac9c-4039-b20f-512653e14941)

Answer (score -2):

Well first with .asmx and i forgot this you cant return an list you have to return an array, so it is expecting an array

As for the second exception your service is not configured /setup correctly. You will need to post more code if you want a fix.

Btw the server event log is in.
Sometimes that can be helpful.
Start Menu->Administrative Tools->Event Viewer. Look in the Application log.

Comment: `1)`the request class has a `List<>` so why is it expecting an Array. `2)` as i have mentioned above when i pass an array i get an exception

Comment: ServiceReference1.foo[]' -- looks like an array to me

Comment: thats the thing i am sure its  List<> not an array in the request class.

Comment: done that numerous times still expects an array. its something related to webservice the list<> maybe need to serialized or something

Comment: @JohnSaunders I didnt think .asmx web services returned .net types by default. Right and no matter what doesn't it de-serialize to an array anyways?

Comment: No web service returns .NET types. They all return XML. See [Basics: How Web Services Work](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/basics-how-web-services-work/).

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yeah they serialize and de-serialize xml, but you cant specify a generic return type like list<> by default right ?

Comment: Yes, you can. There is no problem with that. ASMX services are up to the level of .NET 2.0 technology, which includes `IEnumerable<T>`.